# How to get ACL permissions for a folder for a specific user with C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, permissions, acl

First off, let me ask, do ACL permissions change on per-user basis on Windows-NT? The reason I'm asking is because the [accesschk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx) utility seems to take user name as a parameter, while also requiring an object to check (folder path in my case).

In either case, how do you obtain the ACL permissions ([this stuff](http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/windowsfileapis4_12.html)) for a folder for a specific Windows user with C++? I'm assuming I need to call [GetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but how do I get permissions out of it for a user account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of ACLs is to differ between users. They're Access Control Lists; they control which users have access to a resource.

You're right on `GetNamedSecurityInfo`. It gets you both kinds of ACL's, the SACL and the DACL. SACL deals with file access auditing (rarely used), DACL has permissions. You can break down the DACL returned with `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl`.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still not clear about something. If I call `GetNamedSecurityInfo` to get the DACL on folder path and then use `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl` to retrieve permissions, where does user account come into play?

Comment: Each ACE in the DACL says which user it applies to. For example, one ACE might say "Bob has full control" and another might say "Charlie can read." That's where the user name comes into play. If you are Bob, and you ask for write access, it succeeds. If you are Charlie and you ask for write access, it fails. [Details on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

"In either case, how do you obtain the ACL permissions (this stuff) for a folder for a specific Windows user with C++?"

DACL returns a pointer that you can use to pull values from.

I have a demo program you can look at, it basically loads DACL info from a given file or directory. The link to the page is shown below.

[Sample GetNamedSecurityInfo() call](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/win32acl/blob/master/win32acl.cpp)

"I'm assuming I need to call GetNamedSecurityInfo but how do I get permissions out of it for a user account?"

You can walk the list by calling GetAce() and pull the domain/username from each item.

Again, see my example code which is written in C++.

Comment: Thank you... only if I didn't ask this 2 yrs ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<fileapi.h>
#include<aclapi.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

void printFileProperties(struct stat stats)
{
    struct tm dt;
    printf("\nFile access: ");
    if (stats.st_mode & R_OK)
        printf("read ");
    if (stats.st_mode & W_OK)
        printf("write ");
    if (stats.st_mode & X_OK)
        printf("execute");


  
    printf("\nFile size: %d Bytes", stats.st_size);  
    dt = *(gmtime(&stats.st_ctime));
    printf("\nCreated on: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", dt.tm_mday, dt.tm_mon, dt.tm_year + 1900, 
                                              dt.tm_hour, dt.tm_min, dt.tm_sec);
    dt = *(gmtime(&stats.st_mtime));
    printf("\nModified on: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", dt.tm_mday, dt.tm_mon, dt.tm_year + 1900, 
                                              dt.tm_hour, dt.tm_min, dt.tm_sec);
    dt = *(gmtime(&stats.st_atime));
    printf("\nAccessed on: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", dt.tm_mday, dt.tm_mon, dt.tm_year + 1900, 
                                              dt.tm_hour, dt.tm_min, dt.tm_sec); 
    
}
void printGroupProperties(char filepath[])
{
    LPCSTR fname;

    fname = filepath;
  
    DWORD dwRtnCode = 0;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd = NULL;
    PACL pdacl;
    ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION aclSize = {0};
    PSID sidowner = NULL;
    PSID sidgroup = NULL;
    HANDLE hFile;
    LPTSTR   oname = NULL;
    LPTSTR doname=NULL;
    DWORD namelen=0;        
    DWORD domainnamelen=0;
    SID_NAME_USE peUse;
    ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE* ace;
                 
    dwRtnCode = GetNamedSecurityInfo(fname
            ,SE_FILE_OBJECT
            ,OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION 
            ,&sidowner
            ,&sidgroup
            ,&pdacl
            ,NULL
            ,&psd);
         

    LookupAccountSid(NULL, sidowner,  oname, (LPDWORD)  &namelen, doname,  (LPDWORD) &domainnamelen, &peUse);
    
       oname = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(
          GMEM_FIXED,
          namelen);
           doname = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(
           GMEM_FIXED,
           domainnamelen);
            
//  wcout<<"Owner: " << doname << "/" << oname <<"\n";

    LookupAccountSid(NULL, sidgroup, oname,  (LPDWORD) &namelen, doname,   (LPDWORD)&domainnamelen, &peUse);
    wcout<<"\n\nGroup: " << doname << "/" << oname;      
    wcout<< "\n::ACCESS CONTROL LIST::";
    SID *sid;
    unsigned long i, mask;
    char *stringsid;

    for (int i=0; i<(*pdacl).AceCount; i++) {
        int c=1;
        namelen=0;
        domainnamelen=0;
        BOOL b = GetAce(pdacl, i, (PVOID*)&ace);
        //SID *sid = (SID *) ace->SidStart;
        if (((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE *) ace)->Header.AceType == ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE) {
            sid = (SID *) &((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE *) ace)->SidStart;
            LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid,  oname,  (LPDWORD) &namelen, doname,   (LPDWORD)&domainnamelen, &peUse);
            oname = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,namelen);
            doname = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,domainnamelen);
            LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid,  oname,  (LPDWORD) &namelen, doname,   (LPDWORD)&domainnamelen, &peUse);
            wcout<<"\nUser Group "<<i+1<<":"<< doname << "/" << oname;
            mask = ((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE *) ace)->Mask;
        }
        else if (((ACCESS_DENIED_ACE *) ace)->Header.AceType == ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE) {
            sid = (SID *) &((ACCESS_DENIED_ACE *) ace)->SidStart;
            LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid,  oname,(LPDWORD) &namelen, doname, (LPDWORD)&domainnamelen, &peUse);
            oname = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,namelen);
            doname = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,domainnamelen);
            LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid,  oname,  (LPDWORD) &namelen, doname,   (LPDWORD)&domainnamelen, &peUse);
                wcout<<"\nUser Group "<<i+1<<":"<< doname << "/" << oname;
            mask = ((ACCESS_DENIED_ACE *) ace)->Mask;
        }
        else printf("Other ACE\n");
        cout<<"\nPERMISSIONS:\n";
    //  wcout<<"ACE: mask:" << ace->Mask << " sidStart:" << ace->SidStart << " header type=" << ace->Header.AceType << " header flags=" << ace->Header.AceFlags <<"\n";
    
        if (DELETE & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " Delete" << "\n";
        }
        if (FILE_GENERIC_READ & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " File_Generic_Read" << "\n";
        }
        if (FILE_GENERIC_WRITE & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " File_Generic_Write" << "\n";
        }
        if (FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " File_Generic_Execute" << "\n";
        }
        if (GENERIC_READ & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " Generic_Read" << "\n";
        }
        if (GENERIC_WRITE & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " Generic_Write" << "\n";
        }
        if (GENERIC_EXECUTE & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " Generic_Execute" << "\n";
        }
        if (GENERIC_ALL & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " Generic_All" << "\n";
        }
        if (READ_CONTROL & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " Read_Control" << "\n";
        }
        if (WRITE_DAC & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " Write_DAC" << "\n";
        }
        if (WRITE_OWNER & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " Write_Owner" << "\n";
        }
        if (SYNCHRONIZE & ace->Mask) {
            wcout<< " Synchronize" << "\n";
        }
        wcout<<"\n";
    }

    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR* p1 = (SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR*)psd;

    wcout<< "\n::SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL::" << "\n";

    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL ctrl = (*p1).Control;
        if (SE_OWNER_DEFAULTED & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_OWNER_DEFAULTED" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_DACL_PRESENT & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_DACL_PRESENT" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_DACL_DEFAULTED & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_DACL_DEFAULTED" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_SACL_PRESENT & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_SACL_PRESENT" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_SACL_DEFAULTED & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_SACL_DEFAULTED" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_DACL_AUTO_INHERIT_REQ & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_DACL_AUTO_INHERIT_REQ" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_SACL_AUTO_INHERIT_REQ & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_SACL_AUTO_INHERIT_REQ" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_SACL_AUTO_INHERITED & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_SACL_AUTO_INHERITED" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_DACL_PROTECTED & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_DACL_PROTECTED" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_SACL_PROTECTED & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_SACL_PROTECTED" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_RM_CONTROL_VALID & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_RM_CONTROL_VALID" << "\n";
        }
        if (SE_SELF_RELATIVE & ctrl) {
            wcout<< " SE_SELF_RELATIVE" << "\n";
        }

//  LocalFree(psd);
//  LocalFree(sidowner);
//  LocalFree(pdacl);
}


void printFileAttributes(char filepath[])
{
    long unsigned int FileAttributes;
    FileAttributes=GetFileAttributesA(filepath);
    printf("\nFile type:");
    if (FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE) 
    {
        printf("Archive ");
    }
    if (FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
    {
        printf("Directory ");
    }
    if (FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY) 
    {
        printf("Read-Only ");
    }
    if (FileAttributes &    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) 
    {
        printf("Hidden");
    }
}

int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    char dir[100];
    cout<<"\nEnter the directory path:";
    gets(dir);
    char dirname[100];
    strcpy(dirname,dir);
    strcat(dirname,"\\*");
    //cout<<dirname;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(dirname, &data);      // DIRECTORY
    struct stat stats;
    if ( hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        do {
            std::cout << "\n\nFile name:"<<data.cFileName;
            //cout<<"\nFile Type:";
            char filepath[100];
            strcpy(filepath,dir);
            strcat(filepath,"\\");
            strcat(filepath,data.cFileName);
          
            if( stat(filepath, &stats) == 0)   
            {
                printFileProperties(stats); 
           }
          printFileAttributes(filepath);
         printGroupProperties(filepath);
         
                    
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a C++ program which reads folder/directory path from the user and lists the files, and their properties, attributes and group permissions(ACL).