# How to get the SACL properties of a folder in a remote machine using c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory, file-security

I am trying to read the SACL properties of a folder.
The application will run on the Domain Controller, and it needs to read and update the SACL properties of a folder or file that is present in a member computer.
Is there any APIs available for this?
Can I use the `GetNamedSecurityInfo` to read the file? if yes how should the path of the file be?
Consider the domain is 'Raja.org' and the folder for which I am trying to set the SACL is 'C:\Test'
what should be the path I pass to the `GetNamedSecurityInfo` function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use GetNamedSecurityInfo, where `pObjectName` would be the path to the file and [ObjectType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/accctrl/ne-accctrl-se_object_type) is `SE_FILE_OBJECT`.

> SE_FILE_OBJECT
>
> Indicates a file or directory. The name string that identifies a file
> or directory object can be in one of the following formats:
>
> A relative path, such as FileName.dat or ..\FileName
>
> An absolute path, such as FileName.dat, C:\DirectoryName\FileName.dat,
> or G:\RemoteDirectoryName\FileName.dat.
>
> A UNC name, such as \ComputerName\ShareName\FileName.dat.

Comment: This is for when the folder is shared with other users,
I am asking for situations when the folder is not being shared with any other user.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849221/how-to-get-acl-permissions-for-a-folder-for-a-specific-user-with-c